# click on html button from webview android

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have read json file from server, he include information about html button site:

```
"apply": {
                "type": "click",
                "submit": "#cart-summary-ecouponForm-button",
                "timeout": 5000
            }
"controls": {
                "promo": "#CouponCode",
                "total": ".cart-summary-pricing-webPrice-price",
                "orderTotal": ".cart-summary-pricingTotal dd",
                "coupon": ".remove"
            }
```

html code:

```
 <input onfocus="this.select(); if(this.value == '') { this.value = '' }" onkeypress="if (wci.cart.checkForEnterPress(event)) {wci.cart.addECoupon('ecouponForm', '//shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/cart.workflow:add-e-coupon'); return false; }" id="CouponCode" name="CouponCode" type="text" class="iform cart-summary-ecouponForm-field" value="" size="15" maxlength="99" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = '' }" placeholder="ENTER CART COUPON CODE">

<input onclick="return handleCouponPost();" class="button-standard cart-summary-ecouponForm-button" id="cart-summary-ecouponForm-button" type="submit" value="Apply">
    <script>
    function handleCouponPost()
    {
        if("true" == "")
        {
            var whattodo = confirm("WARNING: Applying another offer via eCoupon will remove the free  offer offer from your purchase.\nDo you want to proceed?");
            if(whattodo == true)
            {
              return wci.cart.addECoupon('ecouponForm', '//shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/cart.workflow:add-e-coupon');
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return wci.cart.addECoupon('ecouponForm', '//shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/cart.workflow:add-e-coupon');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**"promo": "#CouponCode"** = name of input text field in html, me need find this field and set some custom **value=""** programmatically in android activity, and the click on button **"submit": "#cart-summary-ecouponForm-button"**.

Let's say I find button "submit": "#cart-summary-ecouponForm-button", and then find name of function **handleCouponPost**. And I'm simulating the click of a button, but how can I substitute the desired value in the value parameter?